# What could cause my Kitchen tile flooring to come loose and start lifting?

Tags: flooring, ceramic-tile

My kitchen tile flooring was subject to water infusion when it was submerged in several inches of water for six hours, due to a leak in our plumbing. Now the 2' by 2' tile and mortared joints are cracking and lifting. It is possible that the water damaged the integrity and adhesive hold or shrunk the thin set under the tile? Is the only solution to replace the whole tile floor? the installation is a first floor concrete slab construction with concrete thin set used to set and level the two foot square tiles and concrete mortared joints on 1/4 inch spacing. I have never had this problem before and the areas of the water infusion are where the problems are. The insurance company says there is no way that the water is the cause of this problem.

Comment: Jim do you have a picture?  It does seem odd that a little water would have that quick of an effect on thinset/concrete duo.

Comment: was it thinset or mastic?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because user hasn't provided enough info to answer it right.

Answer (score 1):

It could involve the thinset you used. Generally a latex modified thinset will give a stronger bond, especially in a high foot traffic are like the kitchen. If your thinset was not latex modified it's possible that the water degraded the integrity of the bond.

Answer (score 0):

I had a tile floor that started lifting and cracking because the underlying floor flexed a lot over the main support beam.  Once the grout cracked, and I ignored it for a while, the grout worked its way under the tiles and acted as levers to lift more and more of the tiles; and crack some.  Ultimately, I had to clean up a 16 foot section, scrape up the original mastic, and replace everything. Fortunately, I had many spare tiles.  When I regrouted, I used sanded caulk to help the tile system flex with the floor.